# Xamarin Forms : How to place a view inside a relative layout, starting at the right end and expanding towards left?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a design requirement as in image(although this is the simplified version).

I need the end x-coordinates of the button and the image to align and the button needs to expand towards left, depending upon the binded text.

What I have done:

```
<RelativeLayout Padding="0,0,0,0" Margin="0,0,0,0"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

   //other children

 <Image Source="circle.png"
         Aspect="AspectFit"
         x:Name="circleImg"
         RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                  Property=Width, Factor=0.48, Constant=0}"
         RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                  Property=Width, Factor=0.811, Constant=0}"
         RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width, Factor=0.1593, Constant = 0}"
         RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width, Factor=0.1593, Constant = 0}">
    </Image>


 <Button 
           Text="{Binding ButtonText}"
           TextColor="White"
           BorderColor="Transparent"
           RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
              Property=Height, Factor=0.0, Constant=0}"
           RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,
              ElementName=circleImg, Property=X, Factor=1, Constant=0}"
           RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width, Factor=0.1593, Constant = 0}"/>

   //other children


</RelativeLayout>
```

This gives me a button with start aligned with the image's start position, and with width equal to the image. However, if the binded text is long, the text gets truncated.
I tried `VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"` , but it doesn't work.

Is there a way I can specify the ending x-coordinate of the button, rather than its start, and make it expand towards left?

[image]

Comment: This solution can be (I think) ported to xaml http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42490816/proper-way-to-lay-out-in-xamarin-forms/42495376#42495376

Comment: Can you tell me how do i do it the Xaml way?

Comment: You need to know size of the button to position it properly. Not sure how to do this in xaml. Another option is to use stack layouts or the code for constraints. May be somebody else knows how to do this in xaml